# Fully enumerate range from list of breakpoints

Tags: python

This is a bit of a python 101 question, but I can't think of a pythonic way to enumerate a list of breakpoints to all integers between those breakpoints.

Say I have:

```
breaks = [4, 7, 13, 15, 18]
```

and I want

```
enumerated = [[4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14],[15,16,17],[18]]
```

(My actual use case involves breakpoints that are years; I want all years in each range).
I could loop through `breaks` with a counter, create a `range` for each interval and store it in a list, but I suspect there is a simple one-liner for this sort of enumeration. Efficiency is a concern since I am working with millions of records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use zip

```
>>> enumerated = [range(start, end) for start,end in zip(breaks, breaks[1:])] + [[breaks[-1]]]
>>> enumerated
[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18]]
```

Using a zipping of a list with itself in an offset of one (`zip(breaks, breaks[1:]`)  is a known "trick" to get all pairs. This drops the last one so I added it manually.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a generator, it will be memory efficient:

```
def f(b):
    if not b:
        raise StopIteration
    x = b[0]
    for y in b[1:]:
        yield xrange(x, y)
        x = y
    yield [y]

print list(f(breaks))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension and `range()`

```
breaks = [4, 7, 13, 15, 18]
new = [range(breaks[i],breaks[i+1]) for i in xrange(len(breaks)-1)]+[[breaks[-1]]]
print new

[[4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16, 17]]
```